# JavaScript: malfunction If condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jogetworkflow

I have a function to call multiple fields in **Joget Workflow**. But sometimes the inverse function is invoked. If `(pakai)` is less than the `(kuota)` field shown correctly that is `(pakai)`, but if `(pakai)` larger than the `(kuota)` of result displayed still `(pakai)`, should be called `(kuota)`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculation() {
        var kuota = $('[class^=calFiel][name=totalkuota_bbm_unformat]').val();
        var pakai = $('[class^=calFiel][name=totalpakai_bbm_unformat]').val();
        if (parseFloat(pakai) < parseFloat(kuota)) {
            $('[class^=calFiel][name=total_payable_bbm_uf]').val(pakai);
        } else {
            $('[class^=calFiel][name=total_payable_bbm_uf]').val(kuota);
        }
        $('[class^=calFiel][name=total_payable_bbm_uf]').trigger('keyup');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[class^=calFiel][name=totalkuota_bbm_unformat]').on('keyup', function() {
            calculation();
        });
        $('[class^=calFiel][name=totalpakai_bbm_unformat]').on('keyup', function() {
            calculation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: did you add console.log lines to figure out why?

Comment: Can you show me how is console.log works? cause i'm new in javascript

Comment: @FebbyHimawan Don't add `console.log`. Use the debugger to properly debug your program.

Comment: `console.log(parseFloat(pakai), parseFloat(kuota), parseFloat(pakai) < parseFloat(kuota) )`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You can use console.log lines to debug..... there is no need to step through everything.

Comment: @epascarello The debugger isn't only for stepping through the code. Using `console.log` everywhere will only cluster up your code. In fact, the debugger supports evaluating arbitrary expressions so you don't need to use `console.log` at all - the function is for logging values, not for debugging programs.

Comment: LOL, you add a console line and than you remove it. It is not like you leave it there until the end of eternity. I am guessing you were not programming before you could use debugger when all you have was document.write and alert(). A simple console.log line is all that is needed here and the fact the code is running on key presses, that really is going to screw with flow when OP types.

Comment: @epascarello where i put that code? can you show me? i'm confused

Comment: You place it before your if statement.... You than open up the console and see what the values are.

Comment: @epascarello still not working, is there any other way?

Comment: your code seems to work just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/28L53oq7/ - you're not using `,` in the numbers are you?

Comment: @JaromandaX sometimes i'm using if the number is large. but i'm confused why the function still stuck in (pakai) no matter is higher or lower

Comment: define "large" ... more than 20 digits?

Comment: i think around 15 digit, but i write this code in custom html in joget workflow